# use multiple RenderUI under reactive()

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I have shiny app contains multiple dynamic/conditional inputs (next input based on what I choose at previous one). For this purpose I use `renderUI`.

```
output$input1_server <- renderUI({ 
validate(need(base(), "Error"))  
 
df <- base %>%
      filter(age >= 10) %>%
      select(city)

selectInput(session$ns("input1"), "Input #1:", 
            choices = df$city, 
            width = "100%")
})
```

I also have `reactive` which uses *inputs* as arguments for filtering, such as:

```
data <- reactive({

base %>%
#some filters %>%
#some manipulations %>%
#etc 

})
```

Then I use `reactive` **data()** to build a reactive plot

```
plot <- reactive({

data() %>%
ggplot( ... ) %>%
geom_bar( ... ) %>%
#etc...

})

# Rendering
output$plot_output <- renderPlot({ plot() })
```

The problem occurs when I change dynamic input, which causes changing of other dynamic inputs. Then error in `renderPlot()` occurs, **however, despite the error, in a few seconds plot appears**. I am sure that error occurs because of vast number of renderUI. I tried to use `sys.sleep` to give more time for function executions, but it does not work. The code is correct, because when I use it out of shiny app it works.

Comment: Please make a small (minimal) example including sample data that reproduces the error.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), i.e. a complete shiny app that shows this behaviour. Otherwise I'm not sure what your question is. But yes, in general a lot of `renderUI` can slow down your app

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of minimal reproducible example, I'll give me best guess.
You could use `req` to make sure that `data()` and `plot()` are  available :

```
plot <- reactive({
req(data())
data() %>%
ggplot( ... ) %>%
geom_bar( ... ) %>%
#etc...

})

# Rendering
output$plot_output <- renderPlot({ 
  req(plot)
  plot() })
```

Another option is `validate`:

```
plot <- reactive({
validate(need(nrow(data())>0,"Data not yet calculated"))
data() %>%
ggplot( ... ) %>%
geom_bar( ... ) %>%
#etc...

})
```

I hope this helps, but without MRE difficult to tell more.